# What is the use of try and except inside a function in python?

Tags: python, function, try-catch, except

I want to know how to use try and except inside a function and what change will it bring to my syntax of code.

I was trying to use this tags inside one function but error was coming and my program was not running successfully.

Comment: Could we see some code? Preferably a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: This seems like something you'd learn from any decent Python tutorial or book, rather than SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try and except catch errors and you can use them to give responses to those errors.

Here is an example of try and except:

```
variable_name = "Hello world!"

try:
    print(variable_name + 3)
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```